# ERROR: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInlineAnchor')" in console inside browser while checking javascript outputs,?

Tags: javascript, html, console

I have started learning javascript today, I ran the very first program , and even before writing anything in the js file,

ERROR SCREENSHOT CLICK HERE

[image: 1]

> my browser console throws an error : "contents.c10c11b1.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInlineAnchor') "

how to resolve this?

I created an index.html file with just boilerplate code and single output line and linked the working.js file which was empty, but still throws error.

Given below index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Basic working</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hellox</h1>
    <script src="working.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

working.js file is EMPTY , even if I write console.log("hello") in it, it SUCCESSFULLY PRINTS hello on the console , BUT STILL THROWS THE ABOVE MENTIONED ERROR ( pic attached for reference )

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/357354/chrome-hide-extension-errors-in-javascript-console) answer your question?

Comment: This error is not because of your JS file. Maybe it is due to some error in extension installed in VS Code

Comment: @Fractalism Thanks it worked. The problem arose due to the EXTENSIONS installed.

Comment: @dev.skas Exactly! the error was due to EXTENSIONS INSTALLED IN MY 'BROWSER'

Answer (score 1):

## SOLUTION

### 1)HIDE/REMOVE EXTENSION :

The extensions present in your browser are the PRIMARY reason why the error is caused. You can effectively disable the extensions.

### 2)USE INCOGNITO WINDOW:

Using incognito window means that there is no interference of the extensions installed ( provided that you have not allowed access to your extensions in incognito mode ,in that case it can be easily disabled in extension setting )
[Image showing Extension access setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo52R.png)

### BONUS TIP:

- USE EXTENSION MANAGER : This extension allows you to group your installed extensions. For example, you can make a group named 'Default' where all the extensions installed are enabled for use and whenever you want to switch to other purpose such as Web Dev, you can make a group called 'Dev' , which doesn't use any extension installed so that you can work without any interference . Switching between the group is very easy.
  HERE IS THE LINK : [EXTENSION MANAGER](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension-manager/gjldcdngmdknpinoemndlidpcabkggco?hl=en)